# Attempt to make the program MultiThread failed in python 3.5

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I am trying to write the output of my program to file - using Python 3.5 in Ubuntu OS.  Here is what I tried first before attempting to multithread.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz
import ast

def people(email):


       #Checking the names of people with fuzzywuzzy library of python

    return([returns result])

writel = open (r'output.csv','w',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')

with open ('emailfile.txt','r',encoding='ascii',errors='ignore') as Filepointer:
    result = []
    for line in Filepointer.readlines():
        count += 1

        data = people(line.strip())

        if data is not "":
            result.append(data)
for data in result:
   writel.write(str(data)   + "\n")

writel.close()
```

Then I attempted multithreading on python 3 using the following code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz
import ast
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
global FinalOutput
def people(email):


       #Checking the names of people with fuzzywuzzy library of python

    FinalOutput.append([appends returned result])
    print (FinalOutput)
    return




threads = []
writel = open (r'output.csv','w',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')
count = 0
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
with open ('emailfile.txt','r',encoding='ascii',errors='ignore') as Filepointer:   
    for line in Filepointer.readlines():        
        pool.submit(people,line.strip())
pool.shutdown(wait=True)                
for data in FinalOutput:
   writel.write(str(data)   + "\n")

writel.close()
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have gone through threads in StackOverflow related to this issue but found no solution. I still get the same error.
Kindly, let me know what I need to do to make the code run.

Comment: Why do you want it to be multithreaded?

Comment: As the input file was huge and the logic was taking more time for execution, I thought of making the process multithreaded, as the previous process was using single thread only and was slowest. Hence, multithread will certainly give a boost to the complete process. So I thought of it.

Comment: this is not a [mcve]. example `FinalOutput.append([email,names[0][0],names[0][1])` is not valid syntax, and `names` isn't defined (`FinalOutput` isn't defined either)

Comment: ok let me edit it

Answer (score 1):

Python has a great parallelization tool called a Multiprocessing Pool. It's not multi-threading, but it is parallelizing, which appears to be your intent. What we would do is make `people` return a value instead of appending the result to a global variable:

```
def people(email):
    # This is where the magic happens
    return result
```

From there we can create a `Pool` and call its `map` function, which automatically distributes the values returned by the iterable and returns them in a list, in the order in which they were inside the iterable:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with open(r'output.csv','w',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as FilePointer:
    with Pool() as pool:
        FinalOutput = pool.map(people, FilePointer.readlines())

with open(r'output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as writel:
    for data in FinalOutput:
        writel.write(str(data) + '\n')
```

You can also look into a package called `joblib` that has a function that does this in an even neater, more flexible fashion.